# statement in SQL block throws integrity constraint, but not as an individual statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am running a block of delete statements that follow parent/child dependencies. When the block is executed, a statement throws integrity constraints. However, when the statement(s) is/are executed individually, no errors are produced.

I've stepped through the dependencies and delete statements are ordered properly to follow from child to parent. I've added logic to include a parent or child when one or the other doesn't meet the basic requirements that indicates a record to be deleted.

```
begin 
...
delete from rma_receipts where rma_detail_id in (select id from rma_detail where rma_id in (select id from rma where nvl(eplant_id, 1) in (1, 3)));
commit;
--constraint being triggered
delete from rma_detail where rma_id in (select id from rma where eplant_id in (1, 3));
... 
end;
```

no constraint should be thrown as all children in RMA_RECEIPTS are being cleared. No constraints are errors are produced if I run the two statements individually. When the block is executed, this error is produced, which says that rma_detail can't be deleted because rma_receipts records reference it. (but there are none..)

```
    Error report -
    ORA-02292: integrity constraint (FK_RMA_RECE_REF_23860_RMA_DETA)         violated - child record found
ORA-06512: at line 60
02292. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - child record found" *Cause:    attempted to delete a parent key value that had a foreign
           dependency.
*Action:   delete dependencies first then parent or disable constraint.
```

why would this occur in a block? and not on the individual statements?

Comment: did you commit your delete? there is a possiblity that delete is not committed and you are trying to delete the related record from  another session

Comment: @simonare yes, I added a commit after the delete of RMA_RECEIPTS. That didn't alleviate the problem. I killed all other sessions as well and ran again to be sure only my sqldeveloper was connected.

Comment: Did you query and checked `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` table to see if no other table is having FK of base table.

Comment: @xing yes, there none others. I decided to break this statement out and run/commit it separately. I still haven't found the cause of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach of:

```
delete from child_table where parent_key = ...
delete from parent_table where parent_key = ...
```

is error prone if you include the commit between the two steps. Because timing wise you can get into the following problem:

Session 1:

```
delete from child_table where parent_key = ...
commit
```

Session 2:

```
insert a new row into child table for the same parent key
```

Session 1:

```
delete from parent_table where parent_key = ...
```

and you'll get an error because a (new) child record exists.

The solution is easy - remove the commit. Then two possible things could occur depending on who gets in first.

Session 1:

```
delete from child_table where parent_key = ...
delete from parent_table where parent_key = ...
```

Session 2

```
tries to insert a new row - and will be blocked waiting for session 1 to either rollback or commit
```

OR

Session 1

```
delete from parent_table where parent_key = ...
```

Session 2:

```
insert a new row into child table for the same parent key
```

Session 1:

```
delete from parent_table where parent_key = ...
```

and session 1 will be blocked from deleting the parent until session 2 rolls back or commits. In either case, you will always end up with either all parent/child records deleted or all records retained, not a corrupted mixture.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I believe that was part of the issue. I alsofound delete_rules on other referenced tables where one would cascade and another would not. So the error was specified for the table, but was occurring at another step in the script.